# Which is better to use apache commons fileupload or O'reilly MulipartRequest?

Tags: java, multipartform-data

In following which is better to use:

1. [O'reilly](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html)
2. [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/index.html)

(What I'm doing is extract parameter from request with the uploaded file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that Apache Commons is better to use simply because it still gets activity. O'reilly hasn't been touched in many years. I recall switching for some reason, but it has been so long I don't even recall now.

Here [one reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240163/corrupt-form-data-premature-ending-resolved/1346447#1346447) to a bug in O'reilly when used with Struts 2.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons is best to use for file upload

dvantage I see is the amount of coding, with very few lines of code you can replace the Apache commons file upload its most popular library for handling file uploads in Java Servlets,