# java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending

Tags: jsp, glassfish-3

Am having a problem with my Jsp application while usind Oreilly's multipart classes.

The problem is that my app is running very well when I run it on some machines, but when I try running it on some servers for some reasons I dont understand, It throws this error :  java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending
        at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.(MultipartParser.java:205)
        at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.(MultipartParser.java:119)
 The above is just part of the logs am getting.

Someone tell me:- why is it that the app runs very well on some servers, while it gives me a problem when I try to run it from a different one?

What could be possible solutions to my problem?

Am running glassfish server3 on all servers.

Comment: imho this could be the version issue for oreilly classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. It's the server version I was using The latest glassfish release has issues and that was such.. I installed Glassfish3 for linux and it worked perfectly well!

Answer (score 1):

The ancient Oreilly multipart parser has some bugs. See also this related question for an overview [Corrupt form data: premature ending (Resolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240163/corrupt-form-data-premature-ending-resolved). Rather use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) or just the new Servlet 3.0 builtin `request.getPart()` method. See also [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)