# java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending

Tags: mysql, html, api, jsp

hi i get this error when i submit the form  "java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending ",it happens when i add this code inside the existing scriptlet

```
String selectedValue=request.getParameter("sel1");
//out.println("Selected Value is: "+selectedValue);

String select1=request.getParameter("sel2");
//out.println("selected values is:"+select1);

String concat=selectedValue+"." +select1;
out.println(""+concat);
```

my existing scriptlet

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.util.zip.*,com.oreilly.servlet.*" %>
<%
try
 {    
   //if i include here,i can retrive the values but i cant upload the file into database,shows me "java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending "
 String selectedValue=request.getParameter("sel1");
//out.println("Selected Value is: "+selectedValue);

String select1=request.getParameter("sel2");
//out.println("selected values is:"+select1);

String concat=selectedValue+"." +select1;
out.println(""+concat);

Connection connection = null;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ksa";
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
    MultipartRequest request2=new MultipartRequest(request,"/home/adapco/Desktop/output",1024*1024*1024);
String filename=request2.getFilesystemName("file");

File f=request2.getFile("file");
out.println(f.exists()+"----------------"+f.getAbsolutePath());
out.print(filename);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into file1(file_path) values(?)");
psmnt.setString(1, f.getPath());
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();

 //if i include here it shows me null.null

String selectedValue=request.getParameter("sel1");
//out.println("Selected Value is: "+selectedValue);

String select1=request.getParameter("sel2");
//out.println("selected values is:"+select1);

String concat=selectedValue+"." +select1;
out.println(""+concat);

if(s>0)
{
 System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
}
else
{
 System.out.println("Error!");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  out.print("-----------error--------------"+e);
}
%>
```

if i exclude the code from the existing one,it works fine.some times if i include the code after the catch or at the end of the try block,it shows me null.i need to read the index value of dropdowns and concatenate them with a dot. the error was "null.null".the actual out come should be example: 1.1.
here is my html code

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<HTML>
   <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="uploadFile.jsp" METHOD=POST>
    <center>
   <table bgcolor=#38ACEC>
    <tr>
    <center><td colspan="2" align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE</B><center></td>
     </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b></td>
    <td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><select name="sel1">
     <option value="1">Aerospace</option>
     <option value="2">Automotive</option>
     <option value="3">Energy</option>
     <option value="4">IC Engines</option>
     <option value="5">Wind</option>
       <option value="6">Turbo</option>
      <option value="7">IT</option>
      <option value="8">Training</option>
     </select>
     <br>
     <select name="sel2">
     <option value="1">Internal</option>
     <option value="2">Demos</option>
     <option value="3">Best Practice</option>
       <option value="4">Marketing</option>
     <option value="5">Papers & public</option>
     <option value="6">Validation</option>
     <option value="7">Training</option>
      </select></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send File"> </td></tr>
     <table>
   </center>
    </FORM>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very old example you have got.Oreilly multipart parser `MultipartRequest` having some bugs . See related question for an overview [Corrupt form data: premature ending (Resolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240163/corrupt-form-data-premature-ending). Rather use [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) or just the new Servlet 3.0 built in `request.getPart()` method. See also [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: i know but it happens only when i try to read dropdown values otherwise it works fine for all kind of file size.

Comment: When you have multipart request, you can not use `request.getParameter("sel1");` which is 'HttpServletRequest'. Use `request2.getParameter("sel1");`

Comment: I tried the same example of yours with `request2.getParameter("sel1");` It worked and produced selected values. So, Check again and provide proper outcome rahter than "it is not working either..". You should always explain what is happening.

Comment: oh sorry i was trying to modify and forgot to change the the id into name....its working now