# getting error in uploading multiple images using multipart

Tags: java, multipart

Below is my source code and the error

```
MultipartParser parser;
parser = new MultipartParser(request, 1024 * 1024 * 1024);  //this line generates error
/* file limit size of 1GB*/
Part _part;
while ((_part = parser.readNextPart()) != null) {
    if (_part.isFile()) {
       FilePart fPart = (FilePart) _part; 
       inputStream = fPart.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

Below are my headers :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MklIs.png)

Below is my error:

[image]

Comment: Please add the exception with the question. Hope this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240163/corrupt-form-data-premature-ending

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corrupt form data: premature ending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240163/corrupt-form-data-premature-ending)

Comment: Exception e = java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending
java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending

Comment: i have read that but not getting it

Comment: @NAMRATATODI My suggestion is to use latest version of `MultipartParser`. Also try to use `Apache Commons FileUpload` or just the new `Servlet 3.0` builtin `request.getPart()` method. See also How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Answer (score 0):

Check your headers like `content length` and `encoding` ,

You can use tools like **fiddler** to intercept see what is getting transferred.

Comment: i have attached my header can find any mistake in that?